# Is this code (creating many classes) causing redundancy?

Tags: java, class, oop

```
public interface Discount {
    double applyDiscount(double amount);
}

 class StudentDiscount implements Discount {
    @Override
    public double applyDiscount(double amount) {
        return amount * 0.9;
    }
}

 class SeniorCitizenDiscount implements Discount {
    @Override
    public double applyDiscount(double amount) {
        return amount * 0.8;
    }
}

 class BulkOrderDiscount implements Discount {
    private int threshold;
    private double discount;

    public BulkOrderDiscount(int threshold, double discount) {
        this.threshold = threshold;
        this.discount = discount;
    }

    @Override
    public double applyDiscount(double amount) {
        if (amount >= threshold) {
            return amount * (1 - discount);
        } else {
            return amount;
        }
    }
}
```

here's my code. Is this code legit or anything i can improve to get better efficiency/less redundancy? I'm gonna ask input from user such as:
1)student discount
2)senior discount
3)bulk discount

Comment: It's not causing _redundancy_, as each class does its own different thing. What you're doing here is basically the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). [The given answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74910019/6395627) is just a less verbose way of doing the same thing (which could be made even less verbose by using lambda expressions).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need three classes, just three instances. So you can do

```
Discount STUDENT_DISCOUNT = new Discount() {
    @Override
    public double applyDiscount(double amount) {
        return amount * 0.9;
    }
};
public Discount getBulkOrderDiscount(final int threshold, final double discount) {
    return new Discount() {
       @Override
       public double applyDiscount(double amount) {
           if (amount >= threshold) {
               return amount * (1 - discount);
           } else {
               return amount;
           }
       }
    };
}
```

Comment: This could be simplified by using lambda expressions (as it is currently, the OP's `Discount` interface is a functional interface). Regardless, you still have three classes, they're just anonymous now. Well, you only have two, because you've completely gotten rid of the `SceniorCitizenDiscount` class. Though you could get away with only two if you made another method for creating the student and senior citizen discounts (named something like `createXXXDiscount(double discount)`).

Answer (score 1):

Since discount is a *Functional interface* (because it defines a single abstract method) it can be implemented using a [*Lambda expression*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

You can define two method producing `Discount` implementations:

- one for discounts based on `discount` value (like your discounts  for students and senior citizens);
- another for generating bulk-discounts, expecting two arguments `threshold` and `discount`.

That's how implementation might look like:

```
public static Discount createDiscount(double discount) {
    return amount -> amount * discount;
}

public static Discount createBulkDiscount(int threshold, double discount) {
    return amount -> amount >= threshold ? amount * discount : amount;
}
```

*Usage example:*

```
Discount studentDiscount = createDiscount(0.8);
Discount seniorCitizenDiscount = createDiscount(0.9);
Discount bulkDiscount = createBulkDiscount(1_000, 0.75);
    
System.out.println(studentDiscount.applyDiscount(100.0));
System.out.println(seniorCitizenDiscount.applyDiscount(100.0));
System.out.println(bulkDiscount.applyDiscount(300.0));
System.out.println(bulkDiscount.applyDiscount(1_000.0));
```

*Output:*

```
80.0
90.0
300.0
750.0
```